# Multiple connection source for sql localdb

Tags: php, sql, pdo, localdb

I have winform application. It is using sql localdb. Server connection string as below;

```
String.Format(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename={0};Integrated Security=True", "C:\Database\mydb.mdf");
```

I would like to connect same db with php PDO. I installed sqsrv.dll etc. for php and works. But I couldn't connect localdb when winform using it. Codes as below which I tried.

```
new PDO('sqlsrv:server=(localdb)\v11.0;AttachDBFileName=C:\Database\mydb.mdf;Database=mydb', NULL, NULL);
```

Above codes give error "couldn't attach because mdf file is using another..."

```
new PDO( 'sqlsrv:server=(localdb)\v11.0', NULL, NULL);
```

Above code give error "Database object not found"

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
new PDO('sqlsrv:server=(localdb)\v11.0;AttachDBFileName=C:\Database\mydb.mdf;Database=mydb', NULL, NULL);
```

Above codes is working if Apache runs not a service. May be helps someone.